# Designing User Define Functions in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in, user-defined-functions

What are the different methods to create user defined function in excel using C#??
Till now I could only find [`User Defined Functions in C#`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx)

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this article: https://www.quantnet.com/threads/how-to-create-udf-in-excel-using-c-and-visual-studio-2008.1260/

It explains how you create a DLL and use COM to plug it in to Excel so that it appears as UDF within Excel.